# Torch code not running on GPU

Tags: python, gpu, torch, pytorch

I am running an optimization problem in torch. My torch installation is GPU compatible but for some odd reason it does not use the GPU at all when running. Everything seems to be done by the CPU and my local RAM.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.csgraph as csg
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.autograd as autograd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

def cmdscale(D):
    # Number of points                                                                        
    n = len(D)

    # Centering matrix                                                                        
    H = np.eye(n) - np.ones((n, n))/n

    # YY^T                                                                                    
    B = -H.dot(D**2).dot(H)/2

    # Diagonalize                                                                             
    evals, evecs = np.linalg.eigh(B)

    # Sort by eigenvalue in descending order                                                  
    idx   = np.argsort(evals)[::-1]
    evals = evals[idx]
    evecs = evecs[:,idx]

    # Compute the coordinates using positive-eigenvalued components only                      
    w, = np.where(evals > 0)
    L  = np.diag(np.sqrt(evals[w]))
    V  = evecs[:,w]
    Y  = V.dot(L)

    return Y, evals

Y = np.array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
              [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
              [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
              [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
              [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
              [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])

temp = Y[~np.all(Y == 0, axis=1)]
temp = temp[:,~np.all(Y == 0, axis=1)]
Y = np.asarray(temp, dtype='uint8')

n = np.shape(Y)[0]
k = 2

D = csg.shortest_path(Y, directed=True)
Z = cmdscale(D)[0][:,0:k]
Z = Z - Z.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True)

def distMatrix(m):
    n = m.size(0)
    d = m.size(1)
    x = m.unsqueeze(1).expand(n, n, d)
    y = m.unsqueeze(0).expand(n, n, d)
    return torch.sqrt(torch.pow(x - y, 2).sum(2) + 1e-4)

def loss(tY):
    d = -distMatrix(tZ)+B
    sigmoidD = torch.sigmoid(d)
    reduce = tY*torch.log(sigmoidD)+(1-tY)*torch.log(1-sigmoidD)
    #remove diagonal
    reduce[torch.eye(n).byte().cuda()] = 0
    return -reduce.sum()

tZ = autograd.Variable(torch.cuda.FloatTensor(Z), requires_grad=True)
B = autograd.Variable(torch.cuda.FloatTensor([0]), requires_grad=True)

tY = autograd.Variable(torch.cuda.FloatTensor(Y), requires_grad=False)

losses = []
biases = []
#rocAuc = []
learning_rate = 1e-3
epochs = 10000

percentDone = 0
percent = 5
for i in range(epochs):
    if i % (epochs*percent*0.01) == 0:
        percentDone += percent
        print(str(percentDone) + "%")

    l = loss(tY)
    l.backward(retain_graph=True)
    losses.append(float(l))
    biases.append(B.data)
    tZ.data = tZ.data - learning_rate * tZ.grad.data
    B.data = B.data - learning_rate * B.grad.data

    tZ.grad.data.zero_()
    B.grad.data.zero_()

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(losses)
plt.title('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.ylabel('loss')

plt.show()
```

Theres an awful lot of code, but it is a working example, how do I make this code run on my GPU? is it even possible? Any hints or nudges in the right directions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I run your script on my system. It seems that it is using the GPU but the usage is about 200--300 M.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing the cuda toolkit or it doesn't work properly with your PyTorch installation.
Can you first check if this function

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

returns true. If not, you should check if the cuda toolkit works and the PyTorch version you are using is the correct one for your cuda installation.

Comment: It returns true

Comment: How did you check that your GPU isn't used? I don't have any issues when running your code on my computer. It seems to be using the GPU correctly.

Comment: The windows task manager does not show the GPU to be running anything. No GPU load or memory usage. It shows high utilization of my CPU and local memory though

Comment: Looks like a problem with PyTorch on windows then.

Comment: Yes. What happens when you are running one of the pytorch examples?

Comment: I ran an mnist example, it utilized up to 12% of the GPU in the windows task manager, my code uses 0%